# HDFS NFS GateWay mount.nfs: Input/output error?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

HDFS NFS GateWay  mount.nfs: Input/output error?

1.The errors are as follow:

```
[root@xx sbin]# mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl,sync localhost:/ /hdfs_y
mount.nfs: Input/output error

2016-03-10 15:12:06,350 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Exception
804 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hadoop is not allowed to impersonate root
805 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
......
```

2.The process of hadoop, and the user "hadoop" start hadoop.

```
[root@WEB-W031 sbin]# jps
6755 Nfs3
11199 Jps
6163 Portmap
7977 SecondaryNameNode
7720 NameNode
8217 ResourceManager
16762 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

[hadoop@WEB-W031 hadoop]$ jps
6755 Nfs3
7977 SecondaryNameNode
7720 NameNode
8217 ResourceManager
11239 Jps
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

3.reference：
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html#Allow_mounts_from_unprivileged_clients

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you added `hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts` to `core-site.xml` ?

Comment: Thanks, when I  added hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts to core-site.xml, the above bug fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these lines to your `core-site.xml` :

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: So, select my answer as the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: oh,but I have no privilege.